# Wordpress + OpenX PHP invocation = headers already sent

Tags: wordpress, header, openx, invocation, zone

We have a small Wordpress portal that uses local OpenX installation for its advertising needs. The WP theme was built using PHP invocation code for OpenX zones and here lies the problem. In one of the OpenX functions called by the invocation code is a header directive that fills our error_log with GBs of 'headers already sent' messages (the output is started in header.php).
If anyone ran into this problem and solved it (preferably not replacing all zones with js), please share.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is within wordpress, there's no header.php on the openx installation

Comment: The header.php is part of Wordpress and there is the start of output, but the code that triggers the error is in openx: "/admgt/www/delivery/alocal.php on line 2623"